# How to retrieve object info and add it to an array with Parse.com/Express JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, parse-platform

I'm attempting to get an array of video (file) urls from parse.com only if they correspond with a specific playlist ID. The playlist ID is grabbed from the URL.

```
var playlistVideos = Parse.Object.extend("playlistVideos");

    app.get('/:objectId', function(req, res) {

      var objectId = req.params.objectId;

      var queryVids = new Parse.Query(playlistVideos);
      queryVids.equalTo("playlistObjectID", objectId);
      queryVids.find({
        success: function(videoResults) {
          var videoArray = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i < videoResults.length; i++) {
            videoArray[i] = videoResults[i].get("userVid");
            videoArray.push(i);
            //videoArray.push(videoResults[i].get("userVid"));
          }
          res.render('watch',
          {
            videos: videoArray,
            title: "test videos"
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          response.error("No videos found");
          console.log(error.message);
        }
        });

    });
```

I am printing out the array to test and all that returns is:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

<strike>I'm not sure where it is getting these 5 empty objects as I have 8 that correspond with the playlist ID I am trying to retrieve.</strike>

I have also tried the .push method with the commented line and experimented with return(). Still no luck. Basically what I would want returned is "http://example.com/file.mp4", "http://example.com/file2.mp4", etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out JS has .url() which saves me a lot of headache.

I simply used:

```
var holder = videoResults[i].get("userVid");    
videoURL[i] = holder.url();
```

Which is fetching the url string. Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not 5 empty objects but objects that need to be converted into a JSON string. Try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(videoArray));
```

In terms of getting 5 vs 8 results, make sure that the objectId is the exact same as your playlistObjectID (capitalization, spaces, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the info on the objects not being empty. Pointed me in the right direction!